# Why can I not see any vertices?

Tags: modeling

Anyone know why I cannot see any vertices for this shape? I am in edit mode and have show overlays enabled.

[image]

Comment: Probably because you're using the skin modifier. Try Shift-Z to go into wireframe mode and see if they show up.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I switch to wireframe mode I see the edges but still not the vertexes :(

Comment: Please share the blend file in that case so that we can see what's going on. https://blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: I think I might have fixed it by changing to object mode and then hitting apply on the dropdown for the modifiers, and then switching back to edit mode.  I appreciate the help though, thank you!

Comment: Ok. I still suspect that the skin modifier was masking the view though.

Answer (score 1):

The geometry generated by the modifiers is obstructing the base vertices underneath. In your case it's a bit harder to figure out because your base geometry is only a single vertex.

The result of a modifier is generated in a non-destructive way: You can see the result, but you cannot modify the resulting geometry directly, only the base geometry from which it was derived, which in your case is that single vertex at the center.

Edit mode allows you to edit the vertices on the base geometry, not the result of the modifiers. If you put the same modifiers on geometry other than a single vertex, you'd be able to spot what's going on.

[image]

It's still a little hard to see what's actually going on, but you can see some vertices poking out. It becomes more clear when you turn on X-Ray:

[image]

Now you can fully see the geometry underneath. One is a cube, the other a single vertex.

If you want to finalize your modifiers and mess with them in Edit mode, you just have to click 'Apply' on both of your modifiers (in order from top to bottom, so first Skin, then Subdivision). You also have to go back to Object Mode to do so, because these particular modifiers completely replace the existing geometry.

[image]

Now you're good to go!

[image]